# MySQL - Get rows from 2 tables where time distance is 5 minutes, and put them in new table

Tags: mysql, select, join, time, insert

I have two MySQL tables (tbl1 and tbl2), and I want to get the rows from tbl1 and tbl2 which have a time difference of 5 minutes from one another. I want to put the resulting rows in an other table, called combined

```
    INSERT INTO combined ( news_id, col1, col2, col3, col4, quote_ID, quote_DATE, quote_TIME)

    SELECT tbl1.news_id, tbl1.col1, tbl1.col2, tbl1.col3, tbl1.articleTime, tbl1.articleDate, tbl2.ID, tbl2.DATE, tbl2.TIME, tbl2.BID_PRICE, tbl2.BID_SIZE, tbl2.ASK_SIZE, tbl2.BID_YIELD, tbl2.ASK_YIELD

    FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 
WHERE tbl1.articleDate = tbl2.date 
AND hour(tbl1.articleTime) = hour(tbl2.time) 
AND minute(tbl1.articleTime) = minute(tbl2.time)+5;
```

articleDate and articleTime are varchar(11) and varchar(12) in tbl2, time is TIME and date is varchar(10) in tbl1..

Is my query right ? Can I do something better ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody answered (probably it was too easy or sth :D) but I worked out a query that works ! - wasn't that difficult after all

```
INSERT INTO combined ( news_id, tbl1Date, id, date, time)
     SELECT n.news_id, n.tbl1Time, n.tbl1Date, t.id, t.date, t.time
 FROM tbl1 n
JOIN tbl2 t 
 ON n.tbl1Date= t.date AND hour(n.tbl1Time) = hour(t.time) AND minute(n.tbl1Time)+5 = minute(t.time);
```

Is there some way to speed up this query ? Thanks !